# Python Flask User Log In with Encryption

Tags: python, database, encryption, flask

I am trying to create a "Create User" route, followed by a "Log In" route, on a website I am creating.

I need the **passwords** from the **Create User** to be **encrypted** (the route is a POST method, with variable names of "username", "password" ,etc...

I need the **encrypted** password, the username, and the rest of the variables to be **inserted into a database** on the server I am running

I need the login route to confirm the correct credentials. I know how to check the username, but *I can't seem to figure out how to verify the encrypted password that is stored in the database*

I have tried a couple examples online, but most of them are just of creating static users, and I can't seem to replicate it for my database. **Any help would be appreciated.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although

> **Any help would be appreciated.**

is not really a question i assume you want to know how to store passwords securely and check against those stored passwords.

As you are already using `flask` you can use one of its dependencies `werkzeug` which makes this task very easy.

For more details look [here](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/utils/#module-werkzeug.security)

```
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

# when creating a user whose password is 'password'
password = the_password_the_user_specified()
hashed = generate_password_hash(password)
# take a look at the result: it's a salted and hashed password
# now save the user with the hashed password in your database

# when a user wants to log in
# select the password hash for the username the user entered in your form
password = the_password_the_user_entered()
hashed = database_get_password_for_user()
# now compare the passwords
matches = check_password_hash(hashed, password)
if matches:
    # login
else:
    # wrong password
```

So for "encryption" use `generate_password_hash(entered)` and save this instead of the plain text password and for decryption user `check_password_hash(hashed, entered)`. Don't make the mistake and use `generate_password_hash` when the user wants to log in and compare both hashes. That **does not work** because the salts differ.

Answer (score 0):

I am using bcrypt for this https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bcrypt/2.0.0. This is another option for creating hashes.

Where I have two methods in my User class:

```
import requests, bcrypt, pymongo
....

class User:
    def __init__(self, db, config):
        self.users = db['users']
        self.config = config


def pwd_set(self, id, pwd):
    h = bcrypt.hashpw(pwd.encode('utf-8'), self.config['SALT'])
    self.users.update_one({'_id': id},{"$set":{"password":h, "modified":datetime.utcnow()}})

def pwd_match(self, client_pwd, server_pwd):
    h = bcrypt.hashpw(client_pwd.encode('utf-8'), self.config['SALT'])
    return h == server_pwd
```

You need to have salt pre-defined in such cases to use it upon hashing which may not be the best option.
Whenever I have to turn plain text in to hash I use pwd_set and whenever I have to check if the password match I use the pwd_match method to verify that the text is same as the encrypted in the db password hash.

You can also take a look at https://flask-bcrypt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/